# querySelectorAll with including AND excluding attribute conditions (both)

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

The task is to find all  elements which have values in "href" attribute, which suit 2 conditions at the same time:

1. they contain **://** string
2. they not starting with **http://internal.com** string

So I need something like

`const targetHrefs = document.querySelectorAll('[name="list"] ~ ul > li > a[href*="://"][href^="http://internal.com"]');`

where the 2nd condtion should be with operator NOT

Is it possible using the only CSS Selector rule?

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in a `:not`?

```js
const targetHrefs = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="://"]:not([href^="http://internal.com"])');
console.log(targetHrefs.length);
console.log(targetHrefs[0]);
```

```html
<a href="foo"></a>
<a href="https://example.com/"></a>
<a href="http://internal.com/"></a>
```

Comment: that's work fine, thanks a lot!